# When I click on video, it doesn't come out as a popup [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and javascript so please bear with me for any stupid mistakes. So basically I want the video to pop up and start playing like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Create a lightbox
(function() {
    var $lightbox = $("div.lightbox");
    var $video = $("video");
    var $caption = $("p.caption");

    // Add image and caption to lightbox
    $lightbox.append($video).append($caption);

    // Add lighbox to document
    $('body').append($lightbox);

    $('.lightbox-gallery video').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get video link and description
      var src = $(this).attr("src");
      // var cap = $(this).attr("alt");

      // Add data to lighbox
      $video.attr('src', src);
      // $caption.text(cap);

      // Show lightbox
      $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');

      $lightbox.click(function() {
        $lightbox.fadeOut('fast');
      });
    });
  }());
```

I am also willing to accept javascript code but I'd rather have Jquery as I want to learn it more

Comment: I'd hope you accept javascript code since Jquery is javascript.

Comment: @Scath Yeah I know but I'm learning Jquery now, know what I mean :D